# How can I get Uncrustify (which has been unpublished from VSCode marketplace)

Tags: visual-studio-code, uncrustify

I have been using Laurent Treguier's Uncrustify extension but it has been recently unpublished. (https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=LaurentTreguier.uncrustify&ssr=false#overview)

Any insights about this? Is this temporary or not? Do I have an "uncrustify formatting" alternative? I mean, my company requires us to use uncrustify and I would like to avoid going back to sublime for this sole reason.

Answer (score 0):

That's a terribly good question.
Do anyone knows why Uncrustify was removed from VSCode and if it will get back?

Answer (score 0):

I switched to external formatters extension (https://github.com/SteefH/vscode-external-formatters).

Answer (score 0):

I've found crustless by Software Ape to be a good enough alternative.

It's very basic, but does the job.